# How can I delete or replace a mySQL dump file on a database in phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I have just imported a mySQL dump file on a database from another database.

The reason for this is that I am following [these steps](http://dan.doezema.com/2010/04/wordpress-domain-change/comment-page-1/#comment-9160) to transfer a website from one server to another one. I don't think I did it right as I am not getting what I should get on step 8: `in a web browser go to: http://www.yourNewDomain.com/wp-change-domain.php`.

How can I delete or replace a mySQL dump file on a database in phpmyadmin?
I will try to import my database again to see if step 8 works.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are not providing any data it's hard to tell what's wrong with step 8 of your tutorial.
However, to answer your question, I suppose you have imported the entire wordpress database: if the dump was not correct and you want to import it again, you should delete it first with:

```
DROP DATABASE db_name;
```

and then reimport it.
Be very careful, don't do that if you aren't sure what you are doing, you could lose data!

Comment: Hi Andrea, thank you very much! Which specific data would help you to advise on step 8? Do I need to write this line of mySQL in the mySQL query box? Is this the equivalent of `Delete the table (DROP)` ?

Comment: First of all, how did you do your dump? With PhpMyAdmin export? What did you export exactly? The entire wordpress database? `DROP DATABASE` is used to erase a database, which tipically contains many tables, `DROP TABLE` erases a single table.